# Remove duplicate option from select (with multiple select on the same page) jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

Below is my jQuery code. It works for the first select of the page but not the others. The other select's options are removed and I can't figure out why.

Here is the link to one of the concerned page (click on the big blocks to see the dropdown): [my website](https://tvo35400.com/animations-evenements/)

Thanks in advance for the time spent on my issue.

```js
var city = {};

$('.ville-select option').each(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (city[val]) {
    $(this).remove();
    return;
  }
  city[val] = 1;
});
```

Comment: Can you recreate it here? Use the snipplet feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have more than one select on the same page, you would need to iterate through each of them to process duplicate options:

```js
// Iterate through each select boxes
$('.ville-select').each(function() {
  var city = {};
  $(this).find('option').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (city[val]) {
      $(this).remove();
      return;
    }

    city[val] = 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="ville-select">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
</select>
<select class="ville-select">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks!